# Moved to Windows 2012/IIS 8.0 from Windows 2008 R2/IIS 7.5 and websites aren't working

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-server-2012, iis-8

Are there any *special* considerations that need to be made when upgrading websites from

***Windows 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5***

to

***Windows 2012 / IIS 8.0*** ?

Some information that might be pertinent, I don't know, but in my sites, I use `Negotiate:Kerberos` as my **Windows Authentication Provider** and that is combined with an `SPN` inside my **Service Endpoint Identity**.

---

Here's my error:

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Now, the error is complaining about this line under the `<system.webServer>` config section:

```xml
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" authPersistNonNTLM="true" useKernelMode="false">
```

**Here is a condensed version of the `<system.webServer>` config section :**

```xml
<system.webServer>

    <security>
        <authentication>

            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />

            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" 
                                   authPersistNonNTLM="true" 
                                   useKernelMode="false">

                <extendedProtection tokenChecking="None" />

                <providers>

                    <clear />
                    <add value="Negotiate:Kerberos" />

                </providers>

            </windowsAuthentication>

        </authentication>
    </security>

    <!--required for impersonation-->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

</system.webServer>
```

**Here is a condensed version of the `<system.serviceModel>` config section :**

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Deploy.Web.Services.Service" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="DeployServiceBehavior">

            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="DeployBasicHttpBinding" 
                      behaviorConfiguration="DeployEndpointBehavior" 
                      contract="Deploy.Web.Services.IService">

                <identity>

                    <dns value="" />
                    <servicePrincipalName value="HTTP/SERVERNAME" />

                </identity>

            </endpoint>

        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out!

Inside of **IIS 8.0** > **Server Parent Node** > **Features View** > **Management Section** > **Feature Delegation** :

`Authentication - Windows` was set to `Read Only` instead of `Read/Write`. Once we changed it to `Read/Write`, the sites started working again.

So lesson learned, that's one more area you need check when upgrading!

Comment: It might have helped if you actually posted the error

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - I found and added the error message. It wasn't on my machine, so I couldn't screenshot it like I normally would. I'd appreciate an upvote for finding the solution on our own, if you wouldn't mind =D